# Floating right an image alongside a H3 tag

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I find that images floated right won't sit alongside a heading tag such as H3. The H3 tag wants to have its own line so it will always appear below the image.

If I put the image also inside the H3 tag then it works but I would prefer to correct this in the CSS somehow as some of our editors aren't used to delving into the html.

Is this a standard way that H tags behave? Or is it a quirk of my CSS that I can tweak?

I'm doing this in Wordpress using a child theme based on the Thematic theme.

Comment: Without seeing what you've done and you have it's hard to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour as H tags are block level elements. See [this explanation](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/) for more information.

Also note that you can make a block level element not to expand all the width (as it's normal for a block element), for example if you make it float (and decrease its width), changing its display propery, etc. See [this fantastic tutorial](http://www.brainjar.com/css/positioning/) for more information.

Comment: The first link is broken :-(

Answer (score 1):

try putting the h3 tag after the image tag.... they should appear side by side.....

like this:

```
<img src="path/to/some/image" style="float:right;" />
<h3>some heading</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is add `float:left;` to your `h3` tag.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVwTp/).